# Rename Smart YouTube's httpv back to http for all posts

Tags: plugins, shortcode, embed, youtube, customization

I've used the [Smart YouTube](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-youtube/) plugin to embed YouTube videos into my blogs. The way I did it is to replace the `http://` of the YouTube url with `httpv://` as the plugin describes.

But now I noticed that it's much easier to just auto-embed the YouTube videos by posting the normal `http://` url. I would like to disable the Smart YouTube plugin and convert all those `httpv://` back to `http://`. Is there a good automated way to do that?

Here's an example [blog post of mine](http://lexfridman.com/blogs/training/2011/07/01/submission-only-finals/) that now has Smart YouTube disabled so there's just a `httpv://` url lingering there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the Search Regex plugin for mass post editing.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/